# How to relate two object lists?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, view

I have two models related them with a foreign key, pregunta is a question to a especific Comentario (comment).

models.py

```
class Comentario (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    autor = models.ForeignKey (Perfil, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.titulo)

class Pregunta (models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    autor = models.ForeignKey (Perfil, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_pregunta = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comentario_preguntado = models.ForeignKey(Comentario, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.descripcion)
```

I create a view where I want to show only the comments having a question and the questions itself. I create two object list, one with the comments and the other with questions. The problem is that I want to show in the template the first comment and its questions, then the next comment and its questions...
I do not know if this should be done in the template or I need to change my view.

views.py

```
def responder(request):
    comment = Comentario.objects.filter(id__in=Pregunta.objects.all().values_list('comentario_preguntado')).filter(autor=request.user)
    question = Pregunta.objects.filter(comentario_preguntado__in=comment)
    return render(request, 'home/responder.html', {'comment': comment, 'question': question})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access a commentario's preguntas via the `related_name` of their `ForeignKey` relation:

```
def responder(request):
    # use __isnull to filter for comments with existing preguntas
    # use prefetch_related to minimize db hits
    # use plural name to be semantically sound ;)
    comments = Comentario.objects\
        .filter(pregunta_set__isnull=False, autor=request.user)\
        .prefetch_related('pregunta_set')
    return render(request, 'home/responder.html', {'comments': comments})
```

And in the template:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    # display comment stuff
    {% for pregunta in comment.pregunta_set.all %}
        # display pregunta stuff
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Docs on [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull).

Comment: Works fantastic! Thanks so much!